# Use button from NIB

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got a problem,
I have a NIB that works like a reusable view with a button, it's a View that has another Views and inside one of the views there's a button.
That button it's a load more items/rows.

I already loaded the NIB and have the view in my viewController.

My problem starts when i want to use that button in my viewController, create an outlet so i can use him.Already saw a ton of another questions and cant see nothing that can helps me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not make a delegate of that button in custom class and override the delegate in the respective view controller class. That will solve

Comment: Can you explain how can I do that? im kinda newbie @RajanMaheshwari

Comment: Go through this. You will get an idea of delegates
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm

Comment: I've just tried it but I got a problem, how can I execute that code, when I click the button? @RajanMaheshwari

Comment: make delegate as self when you create an object of custom view in your viewcontroller and override the delegate method..

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can use it as an example of delegate 
in .h file

```
@protocol SwipeCellDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) onShowMore;
@end

 @interface SwipeDealCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<SwipeCellDelegate> delegate

@end
```

then in .m file

```
- (IBAction)onBtnMore:(id)sender {
if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(onShowMore)]) {
    [self.delegate onShowMore];
}
```

}

In any view controller that you want to use the button function

```
 SwipeDealCollectionViewCell * cell = (SwipeDealCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identify forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.delegate = self;
```

and you will be able to  the delegate function like this

```
- (void)onShowMore {
NSLog(@"ABC");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In ViewControll:

```
@implementation ViewController ()
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    ..do what ever you want
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView *view = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"buttonView" owner:self options:nil][0];
    ..add subView
}
```

Then in nib,you can connect button target to the nib File's Owner.Try it.